# Write-Error: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Exception' because it is null

Tags: powershell, winscp

I’ve run into a strange error using WinSCP's .NET Assembly to develop an SFTP client. It occurs when I call `PutFileToDirectory()` as follows:

```
try {
   $hostDirectory = Get-PathBelowWebRoot -root $pcRoot -file $file
   $remove = $false
   $session.PutFileToDirectory($file.fullName, $hostDirectory, $remove, $options)
}
catch {
   $errorObject = $Error[0]
   Write-Error $errorObject
   $($errorObject.InvocationInfo)
   exit
}
```

Upon calling `PutFileToDirectory`, execution goes to the catch block, and PowerShell issues this message:

> Write-Error: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Exception' because it is null.

I've used `$Error[0]` successfully in the past to get error details, but for some reason it doesn’t work here.

Does anyone know how to discover the error details?

Output from `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`:

```
Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      3      4
```

I’m using the PowerShell extension to Visual Studio Code, version 1.79.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer doesn't explain your symptom, but - based on your feedback - offers an *effective workaround*:

- There's no need to use the [automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error) in your [`catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) block - instead, use the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) to refer to the error at hand.
- If merely printing the error's *message*, i.e. its *string representation* is enough, you can use:

  ```
  Write-Error -Message $_
  ```

As an aside: if you're using `exit` in a script in response to an *error*, it's best to pass it a *nonzero exit code* to signal to the caller that an error occurred; e.g. `exit 1`.

Comment: Excellent points. I've used exceptions for so long I'd almost forgotten that error codes can be useful, too. I've seen more than one mysterious production problem caused by the programmer (he who shall remain unnamed!) neglecting to check return codes for errors.